# Defining default values to the modal - Rails database views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The `Contact.rb` model has a few status columns

1. pickup
2. arrived
3. in_route_to_destination

.
.
.
and so on

Since the database views dont propogate default values to the model, i am defining the values as follows

```
  def pickup
    self[:pickup] || true
  end

  def arrived
    self[:arrived] || true
  end

  def delivery
    self[:delivery] || true
  end
```

There are 11 statuses and if i follow this way, i need to define 11 methods of the format

```
     def status_name
       self[:status_name] || true
     end
```

Is there a way to optimise this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the best design to have separate columns for each status as opposed to a generic `status` column but I don't know your full requirements so maybe that works best.

You can define them dynamically, though.

```
STATUS_COLUMNS = %i(pickup arrived in_route_to_destination delivery)

STATUS_COLUMNS.each do |method|
  define_method method do
    self[method] || true
  end
end
```